# How can I update OneToMany objects in JPA using the proxy design pattern?

Tags: java, jpa

I have Question That need internal knowledge about what jpa do in proxy desing pattern , let's take a look into What I need to do and what I do.

I have Class Named Exam in Exam we can find List of Question and The Questions Have The List of Answers . I create exam with questions and answers. save it with persist/merge . that I just save Exam object and all Questions and answers saved. but if calling exam into jsf from repository and update questions(add / remove / update) Just remove work well (clear the key from table related with fk)
But! but if add it maybe work or not!
and if update nothing happened! No update.
update I mention work like this -> exam.getQuestions.remove(question).add(newQuestion) that newQuestion and question id is same.
after that I call Repo and update Exam (not update  Question , Exam with all data in it)

What my mistake is and what can I resolve it? is that buggy or something in proxy JPA?
or just my code buggy? :)

The Classes I have in short Version :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "exams")
@Table(name = "table_exams")
@Entity
public class Exam extends StorageInformation {
    @Column
    public String name, predicateExamTiming;
    @Column
    public ExamStatus examStatus;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    public List<Question> questions = new ArrayList<Question>();
.....
@XmlRootElement(name = "questions")
@Table(name = "table_questions")
@Entity
public class Question extends StorageInformation {
    @Column(name = "ind")
    public int index;
    @Column
    public String text;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Answer> answers;
........
@XmlRootElement(name = "answers")
@Table(name = "table_answers")
@Entity
public class Answer extends StorageInformation {
    @Column
    public String text;
    @Column(name = "ind")
    public int index;
....................
@MappedSuperclass
public class StorageInformation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
    @Column(name = "created_at", updatable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date createDate = new Date();
    @Column(name = "update_at")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date updateDate = new Date();
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private UUID id = UUID.randomUUID();
-------------------------------
```

All above is Entity , In the Blow I show you the Repository and Jsf Bean:

```
package ir.mehritco.megnatis.cattell.ctl.beans;

import cattell.beans.android.Answer;
import cattell.beans.android.Exam;
import cattell.beans.android.Question;
import cattell.beans.server.NotificationType;
import ir.mehritco.megnatis.cattell.ctl.master.ResponsiveView;
import ir.mehritco.megnatis.cattell.repo.MasterRepository;
import jakarta.annotation.ManagedBean;
import jakarta.annotation.PostConstruct;
import jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext;
import jakarta.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import jakarta.inject.Named;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
@Named
public class ExamBean implements ResponsiveView, Serializable {
    Exam exam;
    MasterRepository repo = new MasterRepository();

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.err.println("Get exam from repo");
        exam = repo.getMainExam();
    }

    public Exam getExam() {
        return exam;
    }

    public void setExam(Exam exam) {
        this.exam = exam;
    }

    public void updateExam() {
        boolean updated = repo.updateMainExam(exam);
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        response.setTitle("بروز رسانی آزمون");
        if (updated) {
            response.setText("بروز رسانی با موفقیت صورت پذیرفت");
            response.setNotificationType(NotificationType.INFO);
        } else {
            response.setText("شکست در بروز رسانی");
            response.setNotificationType(NotificationType.ALERT);
        }

        facesContext.getPartialViewContext().getEvalScripts().add(
                """
                        notifier('%s','%s','%s','%s');
                        """.formatted(response.getNotificationTypeAsString(), response.getTitle()
                        , response.getText(), response.getTimeNotificationExecuted()));
    }

    public void addQuestion() {
        Question question = new Question();
        exam.getQuestions().add(question);
    }

    public List<Answer> getAnswers(Question question) {
        if (exam != null) {
            if (exam.getQuestions() != null) {
                for (Question q : exam.getQuestions()) {
                    if (question.getId() == q.getId()) {
                        return q.getAnswers();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return new ArrayList<Answer>();
    }

    private Question findQuestion(Question question) {
        if (exam != null) {
            if (exam.getQuestions() != null) {
                for (Question q : exam.getQuestions()) {
                    if (question.getId() == q.getId()) {
                        System.err.println("we find the question id : " + q.getId());
                        return q;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void updateQuestion(Question question) {
        Question find = findQuestion(question);
        if (find != null) {
            exam.getQuestions().remove(find);
            exam.getQuestions().add(question);
            System.err.println("we update Question : " + question.getId());
            updateExam();
        }
    }

    public void removeQuestion(Question question) {
        try {
            exam.getQuestions().remove(question);
            updateExam();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

And Repo :

```
public class MasterRepository {

    private HibernateConnection hibernateService = HibernateConnection.getInstance();

    public Exam getMainExam() {
        Exam exam = new Exam();
        //For main Exam!
        exam.setId(UUID.fromString("5ff225ee-e786-4f20-b139-7bf837c4319f"));
        EntityManager entityManager = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Exam> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Exam.class);
        Root<Exam> root = criteriaQuery.from(Exam.class);
        CriteriaQuery<Exam> all = criteriaQuery.select(root);
        all.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), exam.getId()));
        TypedQuery<Exam> allQuery = entityManager.createQuery(all);
        List<Exam> list = allQuery.getResultList();
        return (list != null && list.size() > 0 ? list.get(0) : exam);
    }

    public boolean updateMainExam(Exam exam) {
        boolean res = false;
        EntityManager entityManager = hibernateService.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction transaction = entityManager.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            exam.setUpdateDate(new Date());
            entityManager.merge((Exam) exam);
            transaction.commit();
            res = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            res = false;
            e.getMessage();
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        return res;

    }

.....
```

I get result of update Exam and return true witch mean exam is updated but nothing happend in Database and The update state for exam that show last updated time no change!

---

After a while fix issue by return exam from database and store in ExamBean! but I'm I wrong ?exam in exam bean class equal with exam in database! after change exam bean the marge call and nothing change just question under the exam , so if I changed with my data it should be same, right?

Comment: You're swallowing exceptions. At least log them.

Comment: yep , I have logger System but in this case just use default print work well.

Comment: But you aren't. In two places.

Comment: ops , I get what you talking about

Comment: thanks , but no error or printStackTrace at print